# Why does if statement continue if condition fails / continue after condition is met?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
i = 1
for k in (range(1, 21)):
  if i % k > 0:
    for j in range(1, 21):
      if (i*j) % k == 0:
        i *= j
        break

print (i)
```

output : `232792560`

This code is written to find the smallest multiple divisible by all numbers between 1 to 20.

My question is why does the `"if i % k > 0"` continue when `1 % 1 == 0?` (line 3)

and why it continues after `"if (i*j) % k == 0"` (line 5) once j and k are 2 instead of breaking?

Comment: Not sure how the program is supposed to work, but a `break` only breaks one `for` loop. For a "complete break", you can use a `return` statement inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

1) The first `if` doesn't continue, but the loop does.

2) `break` only happened for the inner loop, not the whole execution

[You can visualize the execution steps, if you wish](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=i%20%3D%201%0Afor%20k%20in%20range%281,%2021%29%3A%0A%20%20if%20i%20%25%20k%20%3E%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20j%20in%20range%281,%2021%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28i*j%29%20%25%20k%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20i%20*%3D%20j%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0A%0Aprint%20i&cumulative=false&curInstr=239&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 1):

The break statement will only break out of the inner loop. To break out of both, which is what I assume you want to do, you will need a Boolean condition.

You could set a variable to 'True' immediately before the break statement and outside of the inner loop check the condition to see if it is true. If it is, then the break statement will have been met so you can use another break statement to exit the outer loop.